# flutter - How to send device info through sentry

Tags: flutter, error-handling, dart, try-catch, sentry

i'm looking for example how to capture custom key-value, like `Device-Model`, `Android Version` and **class** & **method** etc to sentry.io. but not found so far.

For example below code:

```
 Future doWatchVideo(BuildContext context) async {

    RewardedVideoAd.instance.show().catchError((error, stackTrace) {

        sentry.capture(
            event: null,
            stackFrameFilter: null,

        )
        sentry.captureException(
          exception: error,
          stackTrace: stackTrace,
        );
    });
  }
```

Error & StackTrace are reported but i dont  know how to send User's **Device Info**, also **in what class and method** this error was fire.

Any Idea ?

Thank You

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the `extra` params in the event class

```
final Event event = Event(
        loggerName: '',
        exception: error,
        stackTrace: stackTrace,
        release: '${info.version}_${info.buildNumber}',
        environment: 'qa',
        tags: tags,
        extra: extra,
    );
```

And of course you have to use the `device_info` plugin to get info about the device :

```
final PackageInfo info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

Map<String, dynamic> extra = {};
if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    extra['device_info'] = await DeviceInfoPlugin.channel.invokeMethod('getAndroidDeviceInfo');
}
else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
    extra['device_info'] = await DeviceInfoPlugin.channel.invokeMethod('getIosDeviceInfo');
}
```

For more info consider reading this [full example](https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/094657bb22e986bbb4c9bafd9841cbd8) by Simon Lightfoot